# Data Trigger Binding on Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, datatrigger

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Switcher, Path=On}" Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SliderOnBody" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                    <ThicknessAnimation To="35 5 5 5" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
             <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                 <BeginStoryboard>
                     <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SliderOnBody" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                        <ThicknessAnimation To="5 5 5 5" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                     </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

I have this simple XAML code that makes use of a dependency property called "On" of the control named "Switcher" yet I can't make use of it. The compiler doesn't inform me of any errors. Yet when I run the application and change the value of the property, the animation doesn't fire!

Comment: Did you check runtime binding errors on debugger console window?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem thanks to Clemens' recommendation. I had wrongly defined the dependency property. I had set it as a normal one meaning:
     public bool On { get; set; } while the dependency property register and the event was defined properly...